# Moved site to server software to PHP 5.3: copy function is not longer working. Gives error: [function.copy]: failed to open stream: Permission denied

Tags: file-io, php

I have a script that creates an eBay template via PHP script. It has a function where it uploads the image file to the respective domain via an image_copy.php script on the domain. Anyway, not sure if that matters. But after moving the site over to a server running PHP 5.3 the script stopped working and I started getting an error:

> Warning: copy(temp/0) [function.copy]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/drcom/public_html/v2/techrange/ebay_template_create.php on line 58
>
> Warning: copy(temp/1) [function.copy]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/drcom/public_html/v2/techrange/ebay_template_create.php on line 58

The code and copy function in question is:

```
        $imgs = split(",", $_SESSION["ebay_template_img"], 6);
        if (!empty($imgs)) {
            foreach ($imgs as $key => $img) {
                if (!empty($img)) {
                    if (copy("http://www." . $_SESSION["ebay_template_website"] . ".com/drcom/ebay/image.php?img_source_url=" . $img, "temp/" . $key)) {
                        $img_files[$key + 1] = $img;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Not sure what is going on, and why the copy function is failing. Hope I can get this cleared out, as now I can't run the eBay store efficiently without these images uploading and working! =/

Comment: Make sure the directory you are moving the files to have write permissions

Comment: Hi Dagon, how does one go about getting those enabled?

Comment: ***Permission denied*** - has nothing to do with the PHP version in specfic, perhaps other server configuration changed as well? Like the user who exectues the code effectively? Looks like that user has no access to temp (double check and try with `/temp/` instead).

Comment: Hi John Conde, folders look writable with the correct permissions. I didn't change them during the server move... but also doubled checked that they are 777.

Comment: Tried /temp/ no go... all the temp folders have 777 permission.

Comment: OK, I found out the temp directory had files named 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 that when deleted... allowed the copy function to work. But why doesn't it just overwrite these files? Seems like the old server would have over written them as it never had this error before the move?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I had to delete the previous image files in the temp folder and now that portion of the script is working fine. Not sure why, but the user permissions looked OKAY.